# What are Normalized graphs?

Tags: datasheet, graph

I am reading [this datasheet](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irlml2246pbf.pdf) and there are some graphs that says (Normalized) on one of it's axis...what is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(statistics)) in the simplest case, means adjusting values measured on different scales to a notionally common scale, often prior to averaging.

[image]

In your case, the manufacturer is just showing you how Rds,on varies over temperature *relative to its value at 25degC*.

You should notice that y=1 for x=25. You can then infer that the resistance in the channel will increase 20% if the temperature rises to 100degC.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are talking about the Normalized Drain-to-Source On Resistance vs. Junction Temperature graph on page 3?

If so, normalized means that it is a ratio compared to the on resistance at 25C (notice how it crosses 1 at 25C). So at 100C it is 1.2, i.e. the resistance is 1.2x greater than that at 25C.

A bit confusing I know, it would make more sense it mentioned ratio or something like that, but then again, that is what normalized means.